# In Django, I want to implement a One-To-Many Relationship

Tags: django, one-to-many

I've read of folks talking about using ForeignKey for a One-To-Many relationship in Django, but that's not what I'm looking for.  Suppose I have a model called Club defined simply as:

```
class Club(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
```

What I want is to add a field called owners that is a one-to-many relationship to users (the User model).  I don't want to add a ForeignKey to User that references Club because that will clutter User.  I really want a field in the Club model that maintains the relationship to 0, 1, or more Users that are considered owners of the Club.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I guess it's called many-to-many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [Many-To-Many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationship.

> In a many-to-many relationship, each row in table A can have many (zero or more) matching rows in table B, and each row in table B can have many matching rows in table A. Each club can have many owners, and each owner can have many clubs, for example.

Adapted from: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/sql/9780321584069